# How to press CTRL+ALT+DEL on chrome remote desktop

Tags: chrome-remote-desktop

I am using Chrome Remote Desktop. The remote machine (Windows 7) is requiring CTRL+ALT+DEL to log in, but the command is not making it through. Is there a shortcut or menu to send a command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the options located in the sidebar (click on a small tab in the right side to open it). You can send special keys, like Ctrl+Alt+Del or Print Screen

[image: Chrome remote desktop options sidebar]

Comment: Ahh the SIDEBAR! Was looking -everywhere- for the menu! >_< haha thanks

Comment: Yeah it changed a little bit from previous versions I used (there was a button in the toolbar for that)

Comment: Where or how is this side bar you speak of!? Take me to your leader!